# How do I make my platform move 90 degrees when they touch button unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, rotation, collision

Hello I am trying to make my platform rotate 90 degrees when my player collide with the button. I have no clue atm and can only make my platform go around simentanously. I want it to happen seperatly cause each platform has its seperate button. I am using unity and csharp. 
picture of map
https://gyazo.com/0efce1c230d703b793cf7cab0384ee4e

orange = button

i wanna move the correspondent platform

Comment: Rotate script that i want to only go 90 degress when touch button https://gyazo.com/a1fc9ddc40c89c16e46e8c1c393a1151

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: speed = 0? are you overwriting that in the editor?

Comment: yes but its not the right script i need it to activate only one so i guess i have to make individual scripts for each platform

Answer (score 0):

attach a Collider2D to GameObject make it IsTrigger and attach a script to it on code

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.tag=="Player")
       platformObject.transform.rotation.x=90; //could be Y too 
}
```

something like this would do.

Edit

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Interpolates rotation between the rotations
    // of from and to.
    // (Choose from and to not to be the same as
    // the object you attach this script to)

    Transform from;
    Transform to;
    float speed = 0.1f;
    void Update()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(from.rotation, to.rotation, Time.time * speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: from what i see in his code, he's trying to make it continuously rotate...

Comment: he just wants to rotate when user collides with button as i guess.

Comment: In any case he will need to use IsTrigger collider.

Comment: But it does it instant I want it to do it slowly so the player can climb the platform,

Comment: oh so you need to use Quaternion and Lerp Functions. take a look at Unity docs

Comment: Thanks ill try still kinda noob at this csharp ;D

Comment: you are welcome just go through with unity Tutorials.

Comment: So I tried now and made a lerp but it still just flicks over my startpos and does not turn i dont get it ....https://gyazo.com/8f7a95779e70a7d1f7ccf374d04b4925

Comment: lerp needs to be multiplied by time like `time.deltaTime*0.1f` or `time.Time*0.1f` so in your case `time.Time*journey`

Comment: by doing the time you set rotation every frame by amount of time multiplier you give.

Comment: I c found another method that works great for my map used math.lerp but i got it working like i want now so thanks for all the responds :D

Comment: Can anyone tell me how i make it rotate around its own axis atm it rotate the axis but i want the same rotation point :D

Comment: thats why i told you to go with Quaternion :) Quaternion means Rotation. so transform.position.x=Quaternion.Lerp function would be much better